# PHP vote system, how to stop spamming?

Tags: php

I want to set up a voting system which doesn't require people to log in, but they can vote as they want.

How do i stop people from spamming on voting (sending request to add the vote)? i know using client site scripting can easily stop it (from proper user), but what about server side (PHP). i don't want people to have that url and constantly hit it to increase the number.

Cheers

Comment: Just a note, "using client site scripting can easily stop (spam)" is incorrect. Any client-side scripting can be easily circumvented.

Comment: Without login, the first thing that comes to mind is storing the IP-address along with every vote, and use that to check that the user hasn't already voted. It is not a bullet proof solution, but it will probably get rid of the majority of your problems.

Comment: Elaborating on CanSpice's comment just a little - just disabling Javascript will render all your client-side validation pointless. If a job's worth doing, it's worth doing server-side; client-side code is just to give the legit users an easier time of things, by giving them feedback before they submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) - it's super easy to implement (takes maybe 10 minutes), is a good anti-spam measure, and serves a greater purpose (digitising books).

If you really want to go with cookies, have a look into [evercookies](http://samy.pl/evercookie/). They're super-invasive, and very unethical, but hey, it's your site :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to log their IP and/or set a cookie. The problem with cookies is the client can erase them and the problem with IP tracking is it can block more than one user if a NAT firewall is in the mix, but it will do well for the most part.

Comment: In addition, you can use security tokens that are hidden values in the form that must be submitted with a vote.  If the tokens do not exist, then you don't count the vote.  This way, a person would have to at least write a scraper capable of lifting the codes out of your form before than can try to send fake votes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a vote_tracking table:

```
vote_tracking
    id
    poll_id
    session_id
```

When a user votes in a specific poll, you can update the row with their session id.

You will then need to implement some code to ensure you don't keep issuing queries to determine if user already voted in a poll. If you have an 'active' poll, you can do one lookup, then register a session var indicating that they have already voted, so no matter how many times the poll is rendered, you won't keep hitting the database. Obviously this will only work as long as the current session_id matches, when it differs you will have to issue the first query then reset the session var.

And I'd recommend a reaping mechanism so your table doesn't end up with a million+ rows. If you create a new 'active' poll, truncate the vote_tracking table, or archive it by renaming the table.

Also, the problem with IP tracking is that you will bork users who are behind a proxy, after the first person votes none of the others will be able to vote.

Comment: Not really any different to just storing it as a session var, and still just as open the same pitfall of deleting cookies.

Comment: the problem with IP tracking is that you will bork users who are behind a proxy, after the first person votes none of the others will be able to vote. TOTALLY AGREED

Comment: Sure the user can reset the session id, but by storing it in this fashion he can run metrics on how many votes were cast, and he could even add a timestamp column and determine time of day voting patterns. Unless he implements a login mechanism, there is no solution which will protect 100% from voting spam, but at least this solution has some future flexibility.

Comment: guess we are not live in a perfect world then, i just have to deal with it, with a voting table + cookie help

Comment: Joe's recaptcha idea is a good one as well, as it will stop people from running scripts to corrupt your polls. recaptha will make it so a user cannot submit a vote unless they enter in data rendered by recaptcha. I think if you implement his solution and mine, you will be in a good spot.